# Ideal Java library for cleaning html, and escaping malformed fragments

Tags: java, html, parsing

I've got some HTML files that need to be parsed and cleaned, and they occasionally have content with special characters like <, >, ", etc. which have not been properly escaped.

I have tried running the files through jTidy, but the best I can get it to do is just omit the content it sees as malformed html. Is there a different library that will just escape the malformed fragments instead of omitting them? If not, any recommendations on what library would be easiest to modify?

Clarification:

Sample input: <p> blah blah <M+1> blah </p>

Desired output: <p> blah blah &lt;M+1&gt; blah </p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/). TagSoup emits regular old [SAX](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) events so in the end you get what looks like a well-formed XML document.

I have had very good luck with TagSoup and I'm always surprised at how well it handles poorly constructed HTML files.

Comment: I'm trying TagSoup, but I'm struggling. It just keeps on truckin' and never triggers the error handler.

Comment: I have begun to modify the TagSoup source, and it looks promising. Will post some code if I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I solved this by running a regular expression first and an unmodified TagSoup second.

Here is my regular expression code to escape unknown tags like `<M+1>`

```
private static String escapeUnknownTags(String input) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    while (scan.hasNext()) {

        String s = scan.findWithinHorizon("[^<]*</?[^<>]*>?", 1000000);

        if (s == null) {
            builder.append(escape(scan.next(".*")));
        } else {

            processMatch(s, builder);
        }

    }

    return builder.toString();
}

private static void processMatch(String s, StringBuilder builder) {

    if (!isKnown(s)) {
        String escaped = escape(s);

        builder.append(escaped);
    }
    else {
        builder.append(s);
    }

}

private static String escape(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
    s = s.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
    return s;
}

private static boolean isKnown(String s) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
    if (scan.findWithinHorizon("[^<]*</?([^<> ]*)[^<>]*>?", 10000) == null) {

        return false;
    }

    MatchResult mr = scan.match();

    try {

        String tag = mr.group(1).toLowerCase();

        if (HTML.getTag(tag) != null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Should never happen
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net)

> HtmlCleaner is open-source HTML parser written in Java. HTML found on
>   Web is usually dirty, ill-formed and unsuitable for further
>   processing. For any serious consumption of such documents, it is
>   necessary to first clean up the mess and bring the order to tags,
>   attributes and ordinary text. For the given HTML document, HtmlCleaner
>   reorders individual elements and produces well-formed XML. By default,
>   it follows similar rules that the most of web browsers use in order to
>   create Document Object Model. However, user may provide custom tag and
>   rule set for tag filtering and balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I suspect it is this. Use the following code, it will help.

```
javax.swing.text.html.HTML
```